# Value of variable in string not changing

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a function which generates a script using strings as template for the script. In these template strings I have a variable which I use as index for array item like this:

```js
var annotList = [ { type: "something", color: "blue" }]; // "annotation" objects are pushed in it

function generateScript() {
  var output = document.getElementById("output");

  var idx = 0; // array item index variable

  // template inserted in final template
  var addAnnot_template = 'this.addAnnot({ ' +
    'type:' + annotList[idx].type + ',' +
    'strokeColor: color.' + annotList[idx].color + ','

  // loop through an array named annotList, and increment the index for each items in order to add indexed template for each
  for (var i = 0; i < annotList.length - 1; i++) {
    idx++;
    addAnnot_template += addAnnot_template;
  }

  output.innerHTML = 'beginning of template' +

    addAnnot_template +

    'end of template';
}
```

My problem is that the idx variable value is not changing despite it's incremented in the for loop. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What is `annotList`? At the moment it looks like you're just concatenating `addAnnot_template` with itself for the length of `annotList`

Comment: Generate each new version of your template _inside_ the loop. As it stands, you create a template once, then just append the same string again and again. JS is not reactive by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that the addAnnot_template variable has already been set and will not change unless you set it again.

change your code to this:

```
function generateScript() {
  var output = document.getElementById("output");

  var idx = 0; // array item index variable

  // loop through an array named annotList, and increment the index for each items in order to add indexed template for each
  for (var i = 0; i < annotList.length - 1; i++) {
    idx++;
    addAnnot_template += 'this.addAnnot({ ' +
        'type:' + annotList[idx].type + ',' +
        'strokeColor: color.' + annotList[idx].color + ',';
  }
  // code....
}
```

Also, you can just use `i` instead of `idx` since both start as 0 and increment by one in each loop. Then you can remove all reference to `idx`

IE:

```
function generateScript() {
  var output = document.getElementById("output");

  // loop through an array named annotList, and increment the index for each items in order to add indexed template for each
  for (var i = 0; i < annotList.length - 1; i++) {
    addAnnot_template += 'this.addAnnot({ ' +
        'type:' + annotList[i].type + ',' +
        'strokeColor: color.' + annotList[i].color + ',';
  }
  // code....
}
```